# Using string as integer name for functions

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, variables, integer

I'm currently working on a character item system in Unity C# with permanent power-ups for a game project. As we have it now, the power-up statuses are set with integers (0 for unobtained, 1 for inactive, and 2 for active, since we want the player to be able to disable them.)
As a way of streamlining the code for powerups then and not needing numerous scripts for each item, I considered having a public String variable on the item script where we could input the list name of the integer, and when obtained it would find the integer whose name matches the string text, and work from there.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how this would work, or if it even does. Any help, be it a function that does this or a place to look, or even a confirmation that this is impossible, would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum), which is basically a set of related named integers. When declared as below, the first item gets a default value of `0`, and each subsequent name has a value of one greater than the previous. You can also assign them specific values if you choose, but often the value itself is not used, only the name.

Something like:

```
public enum PowerUpStatus { Unobtained, Inactive, Active }

public class Character
{
    // Create property for powerup status and set the default value to unobtained
    public PowerUpStatus PowerUpStatus { get; set; } = PowerUpStatus.Unobtained;

    // rest of Character implementation omitted
}
```

Sample usage:

```
class Program
{      
    public static void Main()
    {
        var character = new Character();

        // Change character's powerup status
        character.PowerUpStatus = PowerUpStatus.Active;
    }
}
```

You can also get the integer value if needed by simply casting the value to an `int`:

```
int powerUpValue = (int) character.PowerUpStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rufus L is correct in that you should be using an enum in the first place but if you, for some reason, absolutely have to map a string to an integer, then a [[Dictionary][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) is something that will do what you need.  A dictionary will "map" an input value to an output value, so in your case you would map your string to an integer.

As an example, you would setup the dictionary (in a class) like so; each string is now associated with an integer value.

```
Dictionary<string, int> NameToStatus = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
  { "Unobtained", 0 },
  { "Inactive", 1 },
  { "Active", 2 }
}
```

Then you could use it to get the integer value in some function like this.

```
int GetItemStatus(string status)
{
  int res = NameToStatus[status];
  return res;
}
```

This will work, but to reiterate, using an enum as Rufus L suggests in his answer is the optimal solution, and a design you should strive for, if possible.